# How to check if a given HTML file is a Google Search site

Tags: html, parsing, google-search

I have a list of collected `html` sites saved using a browser plugin for history tracking. While iterating through them I want to skip all results which are **Google search sites**. The problem is that for most for many pages I don't have their actual `URL` and research was performed using Google in different countries - so language and country is not consistent across  all result.

So the question is: how for a given `html` file determine if it is a `Google Search` site.